# What replacements are available for formerly-widely-supported behaviors not defined by C standard

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

In the early days of C prior to standardization, implementations had a variety of ways of handling exceptional and semi-exceptional cases of various actions.  Some of them would trigger traps which could cause random code execution if not configured first.  Because the behavior of such traps was outside the scope of the C standard (and may in some cases be controlled by an operating system outside the control of the running program), and to avoid requiring that compilers not allow code which had been relying upon such traps to keep on doing so, the behavior of actions that could cause such traps was left entirely up to the discretion of the compiler/platform.

By the end of the 1990s, although not required to do so by the C standard, every mainstream compiler had adopted common behaviors for many of these situations; using such behaviors would allow improvements with respect to code speed, size, and readability.

Since the "obvious" ways of requesting the following operations are no longer supported, how should one go about replacing them in such a way as to not impede readability nor adversely affect code generation when using older compilers?  For purposes of descriptions, assume `int` is 32-bit, `ui` is a unsigned int, `si` is signed int, and `b` is unsigned char.

1. Given `ui` and `b`, compute `ui << b` for b==0..31, or a value which may arbitrarily behave as `ui << (b & 31)` or zero for values 32..255.  Note that if the left-hand operand is zero whenever the right-hand operand exceeds 31, both behaviors will be identical.
2. For code that only needs to run on a processor that yields zero when right-shifting or left-shifting by an amount from 32 to 255, compute `ui << b` for b==0..31 and 0 for b==32..255.  While a compiler might be able to optimize out conditional logic designed to skip the shift for values 32..255 (so code would simply perform the shift that will yield the correct behavior), I don't know any way to formulate such conditional logic that would guarantee the compiler won't generate needless code for it.
3. As with 1 and 2, but for right shifts.
4. Given `si` and `b` such that b0..30 and `si*(1<<b)` would not overflow, compute `si*(1<<b)`.  Note that use of the multiplication operator would grossly impair performance on many older compilers, but if the purpose of the shift is to scale a signed value, casting to unsigned in cases where the operand would remain negative throughout shifting feels wrong.
5. Given various integer values, perform additions, subtractions, multiplications, and shifts, such fashion that if there are no overflows the results will be correct, and if there are overflows the code will either produce values whose upper bits behave in non-trapping and non-UB but otherwise indeterminate fashion or will trap in *recognizable* platform-defined fashion (and on platforms which don't support traps, would simply yield indeterminate value).
6. Given a pointer to an allocated region and some pointers to things within it, use `realloc` to change the allocation size and adjust the aforementioned pointers to match, while avoiding extra work in cases where `realloc` returns the original block.  Not necessarily possible on all platforms, but 1990s mainstream platforms would all allow code to determine if `realloc` caused things to move, and determine the what the offset of a pointer into a dead object used to be by subtracting the former base address of that object (note that the adjustment would need to be done by computing the offset associated with each dead pointer, and then adding it the new pointer, rather than by trying to compute the "difference" between old and new pointers--something that would legitimately fail on many segmented architectures).

Do "hyper-modern" compilers provide any good replacements for the above which would not degrade at least one of code size, speed, or readability, while offering no improvements in any of the others?  From what I can tell, not only could 99% of compilers throughout the 1990s do all of the above, but for each example one would have been able to write the code the same way on nearly all of them.  A few compilers might have tried to optimize left-shifts and right-shifts with an unguarded jump table, but that's the only case I can think of where a 1990s compiler for a 1990s platform would have any problem with the "obvious" way of coding any of the above.  If that hyper-modern compilers have ceased to support the classic forms, what do they offer as replacements?

Comment: I think the replacement is if you want an assembler, use one. Grown-up C doesn't want to pretend to be one any more.

Comment: Google for "what every programmer should know about undefined behaviour" and find Chris Lattner's blog post (Chris Lattner = LLVM lead and inventor of Swift).

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: If C isn't supposed to be an upgrade of assembly-language, which would allow code to be ported between different platforms with varying ease depending upon similarities between them, what is it?  And why should programmers who need the functionality C and benefited from its improvements versus assembly language be expected to abandon those improvements?

Comment: @gnasher729: I've read that series, but I didn't notice any suggested replacements for the techniques that used to work perfectly well.  I also, incidentally, have yet to see examples where second-order inferences from Undefined Behavior allow any optimizations which could not be achieved just as well with a `__assume` directive [not `__assert`, since the historical purpose of assertions is to ask the compiler to validate things a programmer knows *should* be true, but which might conceivably not be].  Do you know of any?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Also, given that attempts to run with insufficient memory any program that uses four-deep subroutine nesting may (and on some systems, sometimes does) trigger Undefined Behavior, and the Standard does not require that a system with two gigs allow deeper nesting than one with 2K, a philosophy which says compilers and system libraries should not do anything which isn't required by the standard would suggest that compilers should eliminate any execution path which would compel five-deep nesting.  The `malloc` method should also be simplified so that if given...

Comment: ...a value which is no greater than than `sizeof(long)`, it will check a flag and return a pointer to a static `long` variable (if the flag is clear) or null (if set, or if its operand was too large).  The `free` method should then set the flag if given a non-null argument.  Is there any way in which such optimizations would be forbidden by the standard?  If not, I would think they could save tons of code space.

Comment: I can see you have a lot of rant built up and don't want to stop it before it's finished. But it will end with you learning to write `b>=0&&b<32?ui<<b:0` when that's what you mean, and accepting that the extra cycles spent on it don't really matter (since you have a lot more cycles now than you did on your 1990s platform), and that it really wasn't wise to expect portability between platforms to coexist with "shift operators should always behave like the ones on the CPUs I like"

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: I write a lot of embedded systems code, where extra cycles like that often do matter, and where 1990s C would be much nicer than assembly.  If feeding a function into an old compiler would require 30K of code that works, feeding the same function into a new compiler would yield 20K of code that doesn't work, and feeding the new compiler a version that was modified to work with it would yield 31K of code that runs slower than the original, I fail to see the benefit of the new compiler.  Is the above scenario not realistic?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: I agree that code should be written to be portable, but would suggest that the proper way to achieve that would not be to declare that `123 << 33` is equivalent to `__assume(0);` nor even that it's equivalent to some particular value, but say that compilers which go beyond the realm of common broadly-defined non-hyper-modern behaviors must document the situations where they may do so (though they need not document their behaviors in such situations).  Is there anything useful implementations could do without such a constraint that they couldn't do with it?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: I really would like to know: given a choice between a compiler which specifies that none the aforementioned examples will cause unconstrained UB, and one which specifies that all of them may produce unconstrained UB, in what cases would a reasonable person prefer the latter?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley what happens when someone changes the type on `ui`, to either 16-bits or 64-bits?  Your proposed `b>=0&&b<32?ui<<b:0` is quite fragile, and littering the code with assumptions about type width make it a nightmare to port to systems where  `int` is no longer 32-bits.  This seems like less Grown-up C to me, and more arbitrary-and-capricious C.

Comment: @sfstewman: I don't think that's nearly as bad as requiring `ui*=1u*ui;` for safe multiplication.  Personally, I think what C needs is a grown-up standard that would allow code to specify types with as much or as little detail as required, e.g. "I need something that can hold values 0-255, but a larger container would be acceptable as well" to "I need a type that behaves as a 32-bit wrapping unsigned integer, stored in two consecutive `unsigned short`, low-word first, addressable on `short` boundaries"; for the latter, syntax might be something like:

Comment: @sfstewman: `typedef struct { unsigned short dat[2]; default unsigned-wrap value : { dat[1]>>0:16, dat[0]>>0:16; } } DBLSHORT_INT32 };`; putting `default` before an integer-type struct member would allow the struct to be used as as an integer-type lvalue or rvalue [with the operation applied to that lvalue or rvalue] and a brace-delimited list of struct members and bit ranges would make the named item alias the indicated portions of those members, listed MSB first].  The latter syntax would also be a portable way of expressing bit fields [define whole words, then bit-field portions of them]

Comment: I don't know what "mainstream 1990's" platforms you were using, but none of the ones I was using would have admitted many of the things you claim above as correct.  Especially #6.  And #5, and probably #2, #3, and #4 depended entirely on your CPU and compiler, and was just and accident waiting to happen.  Its true the C standard has been bent way out of shape by over-zealous compiler vendors focussing far too much on extreme optimization.  See http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1180 for a proposed alternative safer from abusive optimizers.

Comment: @GregA.Woods: Can you list some mainstream compilers from the 1990s which would have not have behaved as indicated?  I'll concede #2 was dodgy, and I may not have chosen the best examples of behaviors, but with regard to #5 there are many situations when e.g. designing a graphics decoder where it's acceptable for a corrupt input stream to produce an arbitrary decoded result, but not for it to corrupt anything else.  Code which includes enough checks to ensure fully-deterministic behavior in all cases would be slower than code which merely had to avoid corrupting anything other than...

Comment: ...the already-meaningless output data.  Otherwise, I'm curious what sorts of widely-used compilers would have had behavior which differed from any I've mentioned other than #2?  I've looked at the blog you mention and I think it nails down many things too rigidly.  I have no problem saying that following `i=INT_MAX; i++;` the compiler should be allowed to treat `i` as merely being "any value numerically congruent to (INT_MAX+1) mod (UINT_MAX+1)", with every rvalue conversion being allowed to arbitrarily yield a different such value.  That would allow many useful loop optimizations...

Comment: ...but would still uphold laws of time and causality.  I have no problem with the idea that computations without normal side-effects may be performed early, and could thus trap early, provided that implementations are required to document, at minimum, a means by which a trap could be made to yield behavior equivalent to (for C) a `longjmp` call to an earlier-established `setjmp` or (for C++) a throw of an exception.  Annex L suggests a trap-and-resume semantics, but support for those could be expensive.  Anyway, I'd be interested to know what compilers behave contrary to my above.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you wrote in #2.  I think there are typos.

Comment: For #5, I want to confirm that you don't actually mean "trap representation" (as that phrase is used in C99)

Comment: @GregA.Woods: Ignore #2 if you like, though if you're interested the hardware of the ARM specifies that performing any of its shift or rotate operations with a value N from 1 to 255 will yield the same result as performing a single-bit shift N times; some other processors have similar guarantees even though x86 does not.  In some cases, code using this behavior can save a branch (e.g. when decoding a 32-bit value that spans a word boundary, `(lowWord << bitOfs) | (highWord >> (32-bitOfs))` may be faster than using special-case code when `bitOfs is zero).

Comment: As for #6, any code abusing `realloc()` in that way deserves what it gets from a new libc and/or new compiler and/or new CPU architecture.  Don't ever keep pointers into an object that you might have to move!  Use `offsetof()` if you must, but usually you should use the pointer selection operator every time you reference a field in a structure!

Comment: Also for #5 I'm not sure what you're worried about corrupting, though when you mention graphics decoders I'm guessing you're talking about dodgy code that might use such a computed value as an array index (or otherwise use it to do dodgy pointer computations).  Is that right?

Comment: With regard to #6, it would be possible to avoid using anything other than a single pointer to the start of the allocated region, and have code pass around offsets all the time, but if a few items within the data structure are accessed a lot more often than the data structure is moved, keeping the locations of those items as pointers could significantly speed up such access.  Even if one kept redundant copies of the offsets, and regenerated the pointers using only those copies, it would still be helpful to be able to avoid regenerating those pointers when `realloc` doesn't move anything.

Comment: I think you really should just write assembly code in these cases.  You're talking as if you're expecting C to be just some better assembler syntax and you're apparently writing C with deep knowledge about the underlying CPU you're targeting; but then you're complaining that Standard C might cause your dodgy code to go haywire when you port it to a new compiler, or even just turn up the optimizer.  If you want to write *Standard C* then you need to write _only_ for the C abstract machine the standard is centred on.

Comment: The whole reason C was invented was to allow systems-level code which would formerly have required assembly language to instead express things in a slightly-higher-level language; I don't know of any other language invented in the intervening years which is better for that purpose.  I don't think there was any intention that code which knows that it's only going to be run on hardware whose natural means of pointer comparison would guarantee that `p>=base && b<base+size` implies that `p` points within the object defined by `base+size` shouldn't make use of that guarantee.

Comment: Trying to design an efficient operating system like Unix on a system which can't determine such relationships among arbitrary pointers would be much more difficult than on a system which can. I fully appreciate that some hardware platforms may not allow arbitrary pointer comparisons; the fact that one can't use C to write an OS on such platforms should neither imply that C shouldn't be used on that platform for things it can do, nor that such pointer comparisons shouldn't be used in programs which would only be useful on platforms that support them.

Comment: The Google search for "What Every Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior" doesn't work as well as "What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior", which can lead you to [Part 1](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [Part 2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) and [Part 3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html), from May 2011.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm well aware that some compilers use Undefined Behavior as a means of making inferences about what inputs a program will receive, but my question is how one can write programs that can achieve the kind of semantics and performance which were available from simpler compilers.

Answer (score 3):

Modern Standard C is specified in such a way that it can be guaranteed to be portable if *and only if* you write your code with no more expectations about the underlying hardware it will run on than are given by the C abstract machine the standard implicitly and explicitly describes.

You can still write for a specific compiler that has specific behaviour at a given optimization level for a given target CPU and architecture, but then *do not* expect any other compiler (modern or otherwise, or even a minor revision of the one you wrote for) to go out of its way to try to intuit your expectations if your code violates conditions where the Standard says that it is unreasonable to expect any well defined implementation agnostic behaviour.

Comment: The authors of the Standard will generally specify that an action invokes Undefined Behavior if the cost of guaranteeing the behavior on the implementation where that is most expensive might exceed the benefits of guaranteeing the behavior for the application fields where would be worth the least.  This is an invitation to implementers to exercise judgment with regard to the cost and benefit for *their* target platforms and execution fields.  It is not a judgment that the quality implementations for targets where the behavior can be guaranteed at trivial cost shouldn't guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

Two general principles apply to standard C and standard C++:

- Behavior with unsigned numbers is usually better defined than behavior with signed numbers.
- Treat optimization as the quality-of-implementation issue that it is. This means that if you're worried about micro-optimization of a particular inner loop, you should **read the assembly output** of your compiler (such as with `gcc -S`), and if you discover that it fails to optimize well-defined behavior to appropriate machine instructions, **file a defect report** with the publisher of your compiler. (This doesn't work, however, when the publisher of the only practical compiler targeting a particular platform isn't very interested in optimization, such as cc65 targeting MOS 6502.)

From these principles, you can usually derive a well-defined way to achieve the same result, and then apply the [trust-but-verify principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust,_but_verify) to the quality of generated code. For example, make shifting functions with well-defined behavior, and let the optimizer remove any unneeded checks that the architecture itself guarantees.

```
// Performs 2 for unsigned numbers.  Also works for signed
// numbers due to rule for casting between signed and unsigned
// integer types.
inline uint32_t lsl32(uint32_t ui, unsigned int b) {
  if (b >= 32) return 0;
  return ui << b;
}

// Performs 3 for unsigned numbers.
inline uint32_t lsr32(uint32_t ui, unsigned int b) {
  if (b >= 32) return 0;
  return ui >> b;
}

// Performs 3 for signed numbers.
inline int32_t asr32(int32_t si, unsigned int b) {
  if (si >= 0) return lsr32(si, b);
  if (b >= 31) return -1;
  return ~(~(uint32)si >> b);
}
```

For 4 and 5, cast to unsigned, do the math, and cast back to signed. This produces non-trapping well-defined behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many situations where a compiler won't be able to optimize out tests.  For example, on all ARM processors, something like `lsr r0,r0,r1` would behave as `ro>>=r1` for r1 in the range 0 to 31, r0=0` for all r1 values in the range 32 to 127, but on at least some it will yield non-zero values for some other r1 values.  Thus, an expression like `r1 > 31 ? 0 : r0>>r1` won't generally be able to optimize out the comparison even if the `lsr r0,r0,r1` would have yielded satisfactory results in all cases.

Comment: @supercat It can if you use `assert` or similar to tell the compiler there will be no values greater than 127.

Comment: C was designed to be a simple language which would enable a programmer who was familiar with a platform to use a simple and lightweight compiler to generate reasonably-efficient code for that platform.  There is something backward about the notion that a programmer wanting to generate something that behaves like a simple "lsr" instruction with x and y as operands should need to write out a huge complicated mess and hope that a compiler will be able to simplify it, rather than simply being able to write out x>>y and having the compiler generate a platform-specific shift.