# Bitwise leftshift operator distribute over addition

Tags: c, bit-shift

There's a thread on this for logical right-shift operators but I haven't found any for logical left-shift operators. My question is for any fixed word-size language with word-size `w`, an integer constant `0 <= c < w` and variables `int x` and `int y`, is it true that

`(x+y)<<c = (x<<c) + (y<<c)`

?

It appears that this should be true because all addition carries go to the left so shifting to the left should only lose the same sequence of bits on both sides.

Would the relation be true if `c >= w` ?

Turns out I figured it out. Here's the proof

### **PROOF**

Let word-size `w` be arbitrary. Choose any two signed variable `int x` and `int y` within this word-size, and let the integer constant `c` satisfy `0 <= c < w`. Define two new variables `int xW2` and `int yW2` such that they can store bit-sequences of length `2*w + 1`. Copy the bit-sequence of `x` and `y` into `xW2` and `yW2` such that `xW2 = x` and `yW2 = y`, i.e they have equal values. Then `xW2 << c` and `yW2 << c` do not overflow. Moreover `(xW2<<c) + (yW2<<c)` does not overflow as well. But the resulting bit-sequence is identical to `xW2 + yW2` with `c` 0s appended to the least significant bit of that sum. Therefore `(xW2 + yW2)<<c = (xW2<<c) + (yW2<<c)`. It follows from the fact that truncating both bit-sequences by `w-bits` does not violate the equality so it must be that `(x+y)<<c = (x<<c)+(y<<c)`. That's all folks.

Comment: for `c >=w` the result of shifting is undefined.

Comment: The result is also undefined if `x`, `y` or `x+y` are signed integers and the corresponding shift causes an overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it true that (given `0 <= c < w`) `int x,y; (x+y)<<c = (x<<c) + (y<<c)`?

If `c < w` is true and `x+y` does not overflow and neither does `(x+y)<<c`, `x<<c`, `y<<c` overflow, it is true as this is a simple associative multiplication by a power of 2.

Else no.  Overflow due to shifting of a signed integer is undefined behavior.  Shifting a digit into the sign bit in UB.  Overflow due to adding is UB.

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.  C11 §6.5.7 3
>
> An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.  C11 §3.4.3 3

Comment: True but most machines implement Two's-Complement integer arithmetic and I am assuming Two's Complement integer arithmetic. Also I am assuming that any 1s that _run out of space_ are simply dropped off, which I think is intuitive.

Comment: @Sanfer You are missing a big issue. since the C spec says it is undefined behavior, C compilers, even on 2's complement machines, use UB to its advantage to make optimized code.  So in C, you **cannot** count that `int`-overflow will act in _any_ prescribe fashion like "1s that run out of space are simply dropped off"  That is not how optimized C compilers work in 2015.

Comment: @Sanfer  Suggest careful read of   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655664/what-replacements-are-available-for-formerly-widely-supported-behaviors-not-defi

Comment: The standard says it's undefined/unbounded only if the right operand is negative or greater than or equal to the width of the left operand. Here the width of the left operand is `w`. I'm assuming that `0 <= c < w`, so we're within predictable behaviour. I fail to see the issue once a Two's Complement arithmetic is assumed. Two's complement arithmetic defines pretty clearly what to do with overflows, I'm genuinely not sure what the trouble is here.

Comment: @Sanfer  1) "... it's undefined/unbounded only if the right ..." is not true.  That is only _one_ reason. 2) `w` is not the issue. `(x+y)<<c`, `(x<<c)`, `(y<<c)` is the issue. Two's complement arithmetic does defined things, but C is not oblige to follow that, even on a 2's complement machine.  The trouble is assuming that C must follow 2's complement math on overflow.

Comment: I see, thanks for elaborating. Although my question was more abstract than anything else, I'm curious. What is C obliged to follow in terms of arithmetic? Seeing that arithmetic is such a fundamental part of computation and that overflow is inevitable in fixed word-size languages like C, it must be defined to something, but what?

Comment: @Sanfer When, shift, addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. does not overflow (answer above `INT_MAX` or below `INT_MIN`), C must follow that.  `1+1 --> 2`.  When the "correct" answer is outside the range of `int`, the behavior can be _anything_.  C signed integer arithmetic in those cases is not defined.  Unsigned math is another matter.  Moral of the story: do not overflow `int` math.

Comment: Oh dear God. So there's no standard way to detect overflows neither then?

Comment: @Sanfer Welcome to C.  Do not _detect_ overflow - it is too late.  Just do not do it in the first place.  Consider even simple addition: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/simpler-method-to-detect-int-overflow and my [comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/simpler-method-to-detect-int-overflow#comment61303_37178)

Answer (score 1):

Leftshift is just multiplying by a power of 2. So, `(x+y)<< c = (x+y)*2^c`. Lets say `C = 2^c` for easy of reading. so, `(x+y)<<c = (x+y)* C = Cx + Cy = x<<c + y<<c`.

As others have said, this only works if `0 < c < w`...

Answer (score 0):

Well ok, for c values greater or equal than 0 your definition should be correct.

Counter example:

`(x+y)<<c = (x<<c) + (y<<c)
w=4; c=-1; x=7; y=10;
So you got 0111 and 1010:
(x<<c) + (y<<c) = 0011 + 0101 = 1000
(x+y)<<c = 0001<<-1 = 0000 <-- the first 1 gets lost in the transaction`

The rest should work as long as `c<w`, because if it gets shifted to far, both operations still do the same. If `c>=w` your definition will work aswell, as its simply a `0==0` then.

Example:

`(x+y)<<c = (x<<c) + (y<<c)
w=4; c=4; x=1; y=10;
So you got 0001 and 1010:
(x<<c) + (y<<c) = 0000 + 0000 = 0000
(x+y)<<c = 0001<<4 = 0000`

So the main rule should be:

`(x+y)<<c = (x<<c) + (y<<c)` is true, as long as `c>=0`

Hope this is well explained :)

Comment: This answer is not satisfactory. Please elaborate with specific values for x and y that result in a counter-example, if any.

Comment: I forgot to mention c is non-negative. I've added that constraint in my question.

Comment: Your question should be answered now :)

Comment: Oh ! Thanks ! I wish someone could give a rigorous proof on the matter.

Comment: If you shift a value more than its length, it will always be 0 ;)

Comment: But `0 <= c < w` so we never shift a value more than its length.

Comment: @Friwi "shift a value more than its length, it will always be 0" is incorrect in C.  Example `INT_MAX << 1`  is undefined behavior in C.  Code may do anything.

Comment: In Java this is defined, i think^^